# Why does array become null after existing if statement?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, null, windows-forms-designer

I created an *map* array with undefined dimensions that I define in a if statement. The code goes in the if and *map* takes the values I want, until it goes out the if and turns null again. Does anyone know what I did wrong and could help me solve it?

This is the code I have:

```cs
        //Game settings
        const int CELL_SIZE = 70;
        int mapSize = 10;

        //Game Sprits
        Image white_Pawn;
        Image black_Pawn;

        Image white_Tiling;
        Image black_Tiling;
        Image Selected_Tiling;
        Image Path_Tiling;

        //Game variables
        int current_Player;
        bool isMoving;
        Button prevButton;
        Button pressedButton;

        int[,] map;
        Button[,] buttons;



        public Checkers_v2_0()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            white_Pawn = new Bitmap(new Bitmap(@"..\..\Properties\Sprites\white_pawn.png"), new Size(CELL_SIZE - 10, CELL_SIZE - 10));
            black_Pawn = new Bitmap(new Bitmap(@"..\..\Properties\Sprites\black_pawn.png"), new Size(CELL_SIZE - 10, CELL_SIZE - 10));

            white_Tiling = new Bitmap(new Bitmap(@"..\..\Properties\Sprites\white_Tiling.png"), new Size(CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE));
            black_Tiling = new Bitmap(new Bitmap(@"..\..\Properties\Sprites\black_Tiling.png"), new Size(CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE));
            Selected_Tiling = new Bitmap(new Bitmap(@"..\..\Properties\Sprites\Selected_Tiling.png"), new Size(CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE));
            Path_Tiling = new Bitmap(new Bitmap(@"..\..\\Properties\Sprites\Path_Tiling.jpg"), new Size(CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE));

            this.Text = "Chechers";

            InitMenu();

            //ShowMenu();
            InitGame();
        }

        public void InitGame(bool player1type = false, bool player2type = false, int mapSize = 10, int timePerPlayer = 60)
        {
            current_Player = 1;
            isMoving = false;
            prevButton = null;
            Console.WriteLine(map);
            if (mapSize == 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("test OK");
                int[,] map = new int[12, 12]
                {
                            { 9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9 },
                            { 9,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,9 },
                            { 9,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,9 },    
                            { 9,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,9 },    
                            { 9,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,9 },    
                            { 9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9 },    
                            { 9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9 },    
                            { 9,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,9 },
                            { 9,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,9 },
                            { 9,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,9 },
                            { 9,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,9 },
                            { 9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9 }
                };
                Console.WriteLine(map[2, 1]);
                Button[,] buttons = new Button[10, 10];
            }
            else if (mapSize == 8)
            {
                int[,] map = new int[10, 10]
                {
                            { 9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9 },
                            { 9,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,9 },    
                            { 9,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,9 },    
                            { 9,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,9 },    
                            { 9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9 },    
                            { 9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9 },    
                            { 9,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,9 },
                            { 9,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,9 },
                            { 9,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,9 },
                            { 9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9 }
                };
                Button[,] buttons = new Button[8, 8];
            }
            else if (mapSize == 12)
            {
                int[,] map = new int[14, 14]
                {
                            { 9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9 },
                            { 9,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,9 },
                            { 9,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,9 },    
                            { 9,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,9 },    
                            { 9,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,9 },
                            { 9,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,9 },    
                            { 9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9 },    
                            { 9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9 },
                            { 9,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,0,0,9 },  
                            { 9,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,9 },
                            { 9,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,9 },
                            { 9,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,9 },
                            { 9,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,9 },
                            { 9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9 },
                };
                Button[,] buttons = new Button[12, 12];
            }
            Console.WriteLine(map[0, 0]);

            Create_Checkerboard(mapSize);
        }
```

and this is the output:

```
test OK
1
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in Checkers_v2.0.exe
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I expected to have:

```
test OK
1
9
```

**Solution**

> You have declared a field of the class instance, as well as a local variable inside the various scope blocks. These are different. Instead
> of declaring the local variables as int[,] map =, just do map =.    – Lasse V. Karlsen

Comment: When you say `int[,] map = new int[12, 12]`, you are creating a new array. If you want to set the global array, just say `map = new int[12, 12]`

Comment: You have declared a field of the class instance, as well as a local variable inside the various scope blocks. These are different. Instead of declaring the local variables as `int[,] map =`, just do `map =`.

Comment: @Dennis_E: Your comment is incomplete and therefore inaccurate.  The `new` part creates a new array, yes, which is what OP is trying to do. The whole statement is also creating a new array *variable*, which is *not* what OP is trying to do. Your statement fails to make that important distinction. What follows may not add enough for someone who hasn't had that distinction laid out before them.

Comment: You are doing `int[,] map = ` inside if and else blocks. That creates a new variable with name map and the global does not change. You need to do `map =` inside if and else blocks

Comment: Thank you guys, it works now, and I learned something new thanks to you. Have a great day!

Comment: If you want to post an answer, post an answer; don't edit the question and write the solution into the question

Answer (score 1):

I've voted to close this as a typo, but I did want to point out one thing that should make detecting this mistake easier for you

Typical C# naming conventions look like:

```
class ClassName{
  private string _variableName;

  public string PropertyName {get;set;}

  public void MethodName(string parameterName){
    string variableName;
  }
}
```

We tend to name our private variables declared at class level with a leading underscore: `_variableName`

It helps in a few ways; when we're in the middle of a block of code a thousand lines down from the class header, to see:

```
_something = blahblah;
```

we can know "that's a class level variable" without scrolling up to check

---

If we see a PascalCase thing that receives an assignment of data:

```
SomeThing = blahblah;
```

that's a property of the class

---

If we see something without a leading underscore:

```
something = blahblah;
```

that's assigning a local variable declared somewhere within the local method, or its parameter list

---

Try to avoid naming local variables the same as class level ones; they usually serve different purposes and opportunities for crossing the name over might indicate that the class level one should have a better name

In any case, if you do have a `_map` and a `map`, if you've written:

```
void SomeMethod(){

  string _map = ...

  ^^^^^^ ^^^^
   TYPE  NAME
```

i.e. if you've written a datatype followed by an underscore in a method, then it's wrong; in `string _map` you're defining a local variable, you're not setting a class level variable.

As you gain experience with c# these things start to stick out as potential problems - "oh, underscore variable preceded by a datatype, in a method; that's breaking convention.."

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I'll try to stick to the convention and I'm going to modify mycode before I code too much. Thanks!